# Wubi install fails quietly when checking for Ubuntu ISOs

Tags: 12.04, wubi

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 using wubi installer but i have a big problem, never happend before. I am running the wubi installer i say yes on security notification is shows how is loading for a few seconds, and then the loading animation dissapear, and nothing happens. I tried to mount the Ubuntu iso, but no succes again. Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

```
05-26 01:30 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Searching ISOs on USB devices
05-26 01:30 DEBUG  Distro:   checking Ubuntu ISO E:\NFSUG2_DISK2.iso
05-26 01:30 ERROR  WindowsBackend: Error executing command
>>command=C:\Users\TOXDES~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pylEB12.tmp\bin\7z.exe l E:\NFSUG2_DISK2.iso
>>retval=2
>>stderr=
Error: E:\NFSUG2_DISK2.iso: Can not open file as archive
05-26 01:30 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain casper\filesystem.squashfs
05-26 01:30 DEBUG  Distro:   checking Ubuntu ISO E:\NFSUG2_DISK2.iso
05-26 01:30 ERROR  root: iteration over non-sequence
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 57, in run
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 190, in fetch_basic_info
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 803, in find_any_iso
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\distro.py", line 113, in is_valid_iso
TypeError: iteration over non-sequence
```

Comment: You need to look in the log file in the `%TEMP%` directory. It's called `wubi-12.04-rev266.log`. Also check if you have python installed. Please update your question with what you find. You don't need to mount the ISO to install. You just need the ISO in the same directory as `wubi.exe` for it to use it.

Comment: I mounted the ISO!

Comment: I installed Phyton as well, but still doesn't work. The log is very long. I can upload it somehow? Here is a link: http://studentfii.ro/wubi-12.04-rev266.log I uploaded it to my server! Any help?

Comment: I moved the ISO to D: and now is working. I really don't get it! What the hell was that?

Comment: You don't need to install python. Sometimes this can interfere with Wubi which uses an older release of python. Yes the log file helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an ISO in the root of your `E:\` 'drive'. Wubi has some logic that looks for suitable ISOs and for some reason it checks any ISO it finds in the root of partitions. In this case it's trying to look in `NFSUG2_DISK2.iso` and failing. If you just move that (and any other ISO's) from the root of `E:\` into a subfolder it should work okay.

Comment: Yes, i found the answer myself a few minutes ago! Thanks for help!

Comment: Now another problem just appeared. I installed it, but when i restart my laptop, windows 7 is loading, not boot screen appears!

Comment: Goto advanced system settings, startup & recovery settings and set the time to display OSs to 10

Comment: It is already set to 30seconds!

Comment: And is Ubuntu in the drop down box for 'Default OS to boot' on the same screen? (Make sure to leave Windows as the default.)

Comment: I managed to install Ubuntu, using a flash drive, but has created 2 other partitions. How can i uninstall it and put the partition back where they where. I how can i install it as before: inside windows?

Comment: See here: http://askubuntu.com/q/137318/14916

Comment: That worked. Now i would like to know how to install ubuntu inside Windows! I would be very helpful! Thanks

Comment: I thought you already did this? Run Wubi again, if you have any issues look for an existing question that answers it or create a new one. I'm not sure I understand why you want wubi instead of a normal dual boot (when you had it working already).

Comment: Because it had some issues and created two additional partitions instead of one! Thanks foe help @bcbc

Comment: The installer normally creates a partition for ubuntu and one for swap (required for hibernation). You can control this manually if you don't want swap.